# Firebase Auth Multifactor - user object not returning multiFactor property

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to add MFA inside my web app and the **multiFactor** property is missing.
Check the code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier, PhoneAuthProvider, signInWithEmailAndPassword } 
    from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-auth.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    const userEl = document.getElementById('user');
    if (user) {
            userEl.innerHTML = `${user.email} logged in. ${JSON.stringify(
            user.multiFactor.enrolledFactors
        )}`;
    } else {
        userEl.innerHTML = 'signed out';
    }
});

window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': (response) => {
        console.log('captcha solved!');
    }
}, auth);

const enrollBtn = document.getElementById('enroll-button');

enrollBtn.onclick = () => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, 'blabla@gmail.com', 'foobar').then(() => {
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        if (!user) {
            return alert('User not logged!');
        }

        const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('enroll-phone').value;

        console.log(user);

        user.multiFactor.getSession().then((session) => {
            const phoneOpts = {
                phoneNumber,
                session,
            };

            const phoneAuthProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider();

            phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneOpts,
                window.recaptchaVerifier
            ).then((verificationId) => {
                window.verificationId = verificationId;
                alert('sms text sent!');
            });
        });
    });
};
```

In the code above the **user.multiFactor** is undefined. The signIn is returning the user normally, but without this property.

error on console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSession')

The Firebase project have MFA enabled:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLMTe.png)

**************** UPDATE *******************

Apparently change the code to this worked:

```
const mfaUser = multiFactor(user);    
mfaUser.getSession().then((session) => {
```

But now I'm getting this error when I call **verifyPhoneNumber**:

```
VM21778 index.html:315 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tenantId')
    at _addTidIfNecessary (firebase-auth.js:1934:14)
    at startEnrollPhoneMfa (firebase-auth.js:6778:125)
    at _verifyPhoneNumber (firebase-auth.js:8500:40)
```

However I'm not using Multi-Tenancy option, this is disabled in my project.

Comment: Your code is missing step 10 https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa#enrolling_a_second_factor . Did you get to do it?  I get an error, please see my SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069872/how-can-i-enroll-a-user-to-use-mfa

Answer (score 3):

Changed to:

```
const mfaUser = multiFactor(user);    
mfaUser.getSession().then((session) => {
```

and:

```
const phoneAuthProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
```

I don't know if Firebase Auth docs is deprecated or I'm doing something different. XD

Comment: import { multiFactor, PhoneAuthProvider }  from "firebase/auth"

Comment: where did you find the docs for this ?

Comment: I didn't find, I opened the sdk code to checked the functions